# Convert joda.time.DateTime to java.sql.Date and retain time zone

Tags: java, date, jdbc, jodatime

I have the following scenario:

- Swing control that returns a `Calendar` object
- Intermediate `DateTime` object that I use to do heavy date/time manipulation (joda)
- Database connection (`OraclePreparedStatement`) that only takes a `java.sql.Date` object

My problem is that the `Calendar` and `DateTime` objects are properly displaying the date in GMT (which I want), but when I convert to `java.sql.Date` in order to send to the database, the date is converted to the local time zone.

For example:

- `Calendar` and `DateTime` are 2012-08-13T23:59:59.000Z (correct GMT)
- Resulting `java.sql.Date` is 2012-08-14 (incorrect local UTC+2 date)

Below is the code I'm using to do the conversion.

```
DateTime dateGmt = new DateTime(calendarGmt.getTimeInMillis(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dateGmt.getMillis());
```

I don't know how to create a `java.sql.Date` object while retaining the correct time zone. It's also entirely possible that I'm doing an incorrect conversion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Losing Time

One problem may be that java.sql.Date are supposed to be…

> 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

…according to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). That means, the time portion of the date-time is being cleared from your java.util.Date or Joda-Time DateTime objects.

## No Time Zone

As the [correct answer by Gilbert Le Blanc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11938482/642706) notes, both java.util.Date and java.sql.Date have no concept of time zone internally. They store the number of milliseconds since the Unix [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29).

Those classes pull **a nasty trick**: Their `toString` methods apply your JVM's default time zone to the rendering of the string. Very confusing. The `Date` object has no time zone, yet when displayed as a string you see a time zone.

If your java.util.Date object contains the number of 1344902399000L milliseconds since the epoch (1970 start), that means `2012-08-13T23:59:59.000Z` in UTC/GMT. But if your JVM believes itself to be in France with Daylight Saving Time (DST) in effect, you'll see 2 hours ahead of UTC/GMT: `2012-08-14T01:59:59.000+02:00` described in that class' awful string format. The same moment of time has different day-of-month meaning (13 vs 14) in different time zones, with the clock-on-the-wall being past midnight.

## Joda-Time To The Rescue

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4 library can be helpful here. Pass either the java.sql.Date or java.util.Date object to a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) constructor along with the [UTC time zone object](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#UTC) to get a clear picture of the value with which you are struggling.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date( 1390276603054L );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( date, DateTimeZone.UTC );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
```

When run…

```
2014-01-21T03:56:43.054Z
```

To convert the other direction from Joda-Time to java.util.Date…

```
java.util.Date date = myDateTime.toDate();
```

To convert the other direction from Joda-Time to java.sql.Date…

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date( myDateTime.getMillis() );
```

## Update – java.time

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes.

The equivalent of `java.util.Date` is `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1390276603054L );
```

Apply a time zone, `ZoneId`, to produce a `ZonedDateTime` which is akin to a `java.util.Calendar` and a Joda-Time `DateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Kaliningrad" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Now extract a date-only value, the date portion of that `ZonedDateTime`, as a `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. So `LocalDate` is what `java.sql.Date` is pretending to be: a date-only value.

```
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

In JDBC 4.2 and later, you can use the java.time types directly with a compliant driver via `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , localDate );
```

…and…

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class );
```

For an older non-compliant driver, convert briefly to a `java.sql.Date` object to/from a `LocalDate` by using new methods added to the old class: `toLocalDate` and `valueOf( LocalDate )`.

Comment: And what is the way back? Is it: _new java.sql.Date(jodaDateTimeValue.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis())_?

Comment: @thomas.mc.work No, going from a Joda-Time DateTime object to a java.util.Date is much easier than that… just call the `toDate` method. Like this: `java.util.Date date = myDateTime.toDate();`. For a java.**sql**.Date, you were close but don't need the UTC as Millis are always UTC. So: `java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date( myDateTime.getMillis() );`

Comment: But when i convert java.sql.Date from database with the value "2014-02-01" in this way then i get "2014-01-31T23:00:00.000Z" (my time zone is CET). When i use the time zone CET then it is correct: "2014-02-01T00:00:00.000Z". Why is that?

Comment: @thomas.mc.work (a) Avoid those three-letter time zone codes like "CET". User a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). (b) When parsing string to DateTime, pass the time zone in which to frame the time or else your JVM's default is used. Example: `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2014-02-01", DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Berlin" ) );` → `2014-02-01T00:00:00.000+01:00` (c) Germany is 1 hour ahead of UTC. So the first moment of the day 00:00:00 in Hanover *is* 23:00:00 the previous day in UTC. Being "ahead" of UTC means moving backwards to UTC.

Answer (score 7):

The internal representation of a `java.sql.Date` is the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT.

Are you sure that you're not looking at a `toString` problem?  The method `toGMTString()`, although depreciated, still exists.

Comment: This could be the issue since I have had craziness happen with java.util.Date.toString() and its loss of time zone information. I'll test something and report back.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may need to add in configuration file TIMEZONE=GMT

In web application this is defined in web.xml

```
<context-param> <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</p‌​aram-name> <param-value>true</param-value> </context-param>
```

Regards