# Removing seconds from a sql Time in java

Tags: java

I am taking data from a sql database and then displaying this data in the form of graphs. A graph I am making bases the data off of the time. I want to get rid of the seconds because it is useless for my application and takes up room.

I tried using a calender object to remove the seconds from it like this:

```
    ArrayList<Time> ints3 = new ArrayList<Time>();
    while ( rs.next() ){
        ints3.add(rs.getTime(ints.get(0)));
    }
    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
    instance.setTime(ints3.get(1));
    instance.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    ints3.set(1, (Time) instance.getTime());
```

This did not work however because you can not cast a java.util date into a sql time. How can I go about removing the seconds part of the time.

Comment: I'm quite uncertain whether seconds set to "0" take less "room" than seconds set to "59". Therfore: Is this a formatting isse probably, not showing the seconds on the graph only?

Comment: I actually figured it out, but I did not want it set to 0, I wanted it to not show the seconds at all. Lets say the time it gets from the sql database is 14:22:31 I wanted 14:22. I mean preferably it would round correctly but I ended up just converting it to a string then taking the substring of the whole thing minus the last three characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your need (which is to symbolize the Date without displaying the seconds) is to use the DateFormat class. Given that Time is a java.sql.Time object, convert it to a Date first:

```
Date myDate=new Date(Time.getTime());
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
String myDateStr=df.format(myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to comment this but I do not have enough reputation points. I believe this answer could help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21250071/2987444

You could use Jodatimes, methods to add/take away seconds and then convert back

Comment: I recommend you to write an answer rather than making pass a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*This did not work however because you can not cast a java.util date into a sql time* That's strange because [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) extends `java.util.Date`.

You're downcasting the result of `Calendar#getTime` but this won't work. Instead, create an instance of `java.sql.Time` and pass as parameter the time in millis:

```
//ints3.set(1, (Time) instance.getTime())
ints3.set(1, new Time(instance.getTime().getTime()));
```

Still, it will be *way better* to change `ArrayList<Time>` to `List<Date>` (`java.util.Date`).

Comment: That worked but it still has 00 for the seconds, Should I convert it to a string and remove the last 3 chars or is there a better method?

Comment: If your problem is due to presentation, then you could use `SimpleDateFormat` which is the class meant to format `Date` objects into `String` and parse `String` into `Date`s.

Comment: Thanks Worked great, I used dateFormat before I dont know why I didnt think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use setTime method in Time class which accepts a long value that you can get by calling getTimeInMillis() of Calendar class(in your case after clearing seconds part).But even if you do that the Time object will take Hour,minute and the seconds part(with seconds part set to zero).If you don't want seconds part in the display then you can use concatenation of getHours and getMinutes methods of Time class.